# Equivalent of Python's dict.update for STL maps in C++

Tags: c++, hash-map, c++17

[`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) objects in Python have an [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method that can be used to extend one dictionary with all items from another, possibly overwriting entries that already exist.  I find this function very useful from time to time.

The associative containers from the C++ standard library ([`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)) do not provide a direct analogue for this functionality so I wrote the following utility functions.

Comments regarding any aspect of the code are welcome.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <utility>

namespace codereview
{

    template <typename DictT>
    void update(DictT& dst, const DictT& src)
    {
        for (const auto& [key, value] : src) {
            dst.insert_or_assign(key, value);
        }
    }

    template <typename DictT>
    void update(DictT& dst, DictT&& src) noexcept
    {
        // Equal allocators are a precondition for splicing nodes
        assert(src.get_allocator() == dst.get_allocator());
        dst.merge(src);
        while (!src.empty()) {
            auto node = src.extract(src.cbegin());
            dst.extract(node.key());
            dst.insert(std::move(node));
        }
    }

}  // namespace codereview
```

Comment: I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462946/why-insert-or-assign-doesnt-have-iterator-overload) about the weird interface on SO. Feel free to join in guys, this looks really interesting. Might as well be a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not thinking laterally here.  If you `std::swap()` your two inputs, then you can `merge()` the original into the new, and the contents of the new map will prevail.

Here's what I mean:

```
namespace codereview
{
    template <typename DictT>
    void update(DictT& dst, DictT src)
    {
        std::swap(dst, src);
        dst.merge(src);
    }

}  // namespace codereview
```

```
// Test
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template<typename Map>
void print(const Map& x)
{
    for (auto const& i: x)
        std::cout << i.first << "=" << i.second << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    using Map = std::map<int, const char*>;
    Map a { {0, "zero"}, {1, "one"} };
    const Map b { {0, "nothing"}, {2, "two"}};

    print(a);

    // test lvalue argument
    codereview::update(a, b);
    print(a);

    // test rvalue argument
    codereview::update(a, Map{{3, "three"}, {0, "nada"}});
    print(a);
}
```

### Output

```
0=zero 1=one 
0=nothing 1=one 2=two 
0=nada 1=one 2=two 3=three
```

Note that I changed the method signature to accept `src` by copy - the compiler will move-construct into `src` if it can, but if not, we'll need a copy so that we don't perturb the caller's version when we swap.

Comment: I see now. Really good solution. I kind of ignored effects of swap

Comment: Nice! This solution is indeed more elegant and probably also more efficient than mine.